# How Do Implement ViewPager PagerTitleStrip?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am a noob to android and i have been using tutorials to construct a viewpager layout.  However, i have not been able to find a tutorial that also shows how to implement the pagertitle strip as well.  I have been able to gather bits and pieces and have the bar displaying, but I don't know how make the text display properly.  Currently it shows multiple titles at once and loses sync with the pages.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class MyPagerActivity extends Activity {

PagerTitleStrip mTitleStrip;
String myTitle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mypagermain);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    mTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.title_strip);


    //some code
}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.news;              
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            LinearLayout layout0=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.LLnews);
            WebView newsfeed = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewnews);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;

        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.coinshows;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            LinearLayout layout1=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.LLcoinshows);
            WebView coinshows = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewcoinshows);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;


        }
        return resId;
}

}

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return myTitle;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip). It's usage is very simple and the it emulates Play Store look&feel, very nice.

> **Usage**
>
> 1.For a working implementation of this project see the sample/ folder.
>
> Include the PagerSlidingTabStrip widget in your view. This should
>      usually be placed adjacent to the ViewPager it represents.

```
  <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="48dip" />
```

> 2.In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), bind the widget to the ViewPager.

```
  // Set the pager with an adapter  
  ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  
  pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

  // Bind the widget to the adapter  
  PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs); 
  tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

> 3.(Optional) If you use an OnPageChangeListener with your view pager you should set it in the widget rather than on the pager directly.

```
  // continued from above 
  tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
```